# SQFlite - delete row through join throws: near LEFT syntax error

Tags: sqlite

I am currently working on a shopping list, where the user can have multiple lists and is able to add different items on the different tables. It is also possible to check those items. Everything works fine, but when I want to delete some of the checked items it throws me an error:

> D/Sqflite (10847): [Thread[Sqflite,5,main]] DELETE FROM shoppingTitles
>   LEFT JOIN shopping ON shoppingTitles.idShopping = shopping.id LEFT
>   JOIN listTitles ON shoppingTitles.idTitles = listTitles.id WHERE
>   shopping.checked = 1 AND listTitles.titleName = ? [Einkaufsliste]
>   E/SQLiteLog(10847): (1) near "LEFT": syntax error

This is my sql query:

```
DELETE 
  FROM shoppingTitles 
    LEFT JOIN shopping ON shoppingTitles.idShopping = shopping.id
    LEFT JOIN listTitles ON shoppingTitles.idTitles = listTitles.id
  WHERE shopping.checked = 1
  AND listTitles.titleName = "Liste"
```

I hope somebody is able to help me. Thanks in advance XD

---

*FOUND MY SOLUTION BASED ON THE ANSWER provided by* **Akn**

```
DELETE FROM shoppingTitles 
WHERE idShopping IN (
  SELECT shoppingTitles.idShopping
  FROM shoppingTitles, shopping, listTitles
  WHERE shopping.id = shoppingTitles.idShopping
  AND shoppingTitles.idTitles = listTitles.id
  AND shopping.checked = 1
  AND listTitles.titleName = "Liste"
)
```

Comment: That's not really android, ios, dart, or flutter related, only SQLite related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DELETE S
FROM
  shoppingTitles S
  LEFT JOIN shopping ON S.idShopping = shopping.id
  LEFT JOIN listTitles ON S.idTitles = listTitles.id
WHERE
  shopping.checked = 1
  AND listTitles.titleName = "Liste"
```

**Update:**
Guess, there is no support for `JOINs` within `DELETE` statements so you better find a way to use `SELECT` statement.
Below `SELECT` statement will return an id. If it matches with your myIdShopping, it'll be deleted. I couldn't check/run the code. Hope it works.

```
DELETE FROM
  shoppingTitles
WHERE
  myIdShopping IN(
    SELECT
      shoppingTitles.idShopping
    FROM
      shoppingTitles
      LEFT JOIN shopping ON shoppingTitles.idShopping = shopping.id
      LEFT JOIN listTitles ON shoppingTitles.idTitles = listTitles.id
    WHERE
      shopping.checked = 1
      AND listTitles.titleName = "Liste"
  )
```

Comment: If i try it like this, then it throws an error, that says: **near "S": syntax error**

Comment: Seems there is no support for JOINs within DELETE in SQLite. Kindly, check and try my updated answer.